# Where do I run code after successful login in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

I want to register a user log in immediately after successful login. I found a suggestion that I can use EventServiceProvider to listen to LOGIN event like this:

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    // Fired on successful logins...
    $events->listen('auth.login', function ($user, $remember) {
        //
    });
}
```

However, that throws this error:

`Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot(App\Providers\DispatcherContract $events) must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot()`
So, where is the approriate place to register Log immediately after user Logs in in Laravel 8? or how do I format the above code to work for Laravel 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a listener using `php artisan make:listener` and define your logic in the **handle** method of that listener class. Then bind listener class to  the event in `$listen` property of **EventServiceProvider**

```
protected $listen = [
    \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::class=>[
        \App\Listener\YourCustomListener::class
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the best solution I have found on the internet

Comment: php artisan make:listener LoginSuccessful --event=Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login 
https://codingdriver.com/laravel-login-event-listener-example-tutorial.html